# jooq configuration input parameter on call sp

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, stored-procedures, jooq

we had used code-generator in jooq 3.2 to call stored procedure in oracle 11g. We created needed classes correctly but to call sp in Eclipse need Configuration parameter. So now I don't know how to create Configuration parameter? I googled a lot and didn't reach any thing. Thanks in advance.

name of stored procedure is oracle 11g -> `City_Select`

in Eclipse ->

```
ir.samin.omid.Routines R = new ir.samin.omid.Routines();
R.city_Select( configuration,123);
```

Comment: What jOOQ version is this?

Comment: We had used jooq 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ's [`Configuration`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Configuration.html) lifecycle is described in [this page of the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context). Often, however, you do not need direct access to the `Configuration` object itself, as you will be operating on [`DSLContext`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html), which wraps `Configuration`, e.g.

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
ctx.select(...);
```

If you do need a `Configuration` reference, e.g. for calling stored procedures, you can either [extract it from such a `DSLContext`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#configuration%28%29):

```
Configuration configuration = ctx.configuration();
```

... [or create your own](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConfiguration.html):

```
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration().set(...).set(...);
```